# Updating Access 2003 to 2007, potential issues?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2007

I've written an Access 2003 application to handle internal things at my company over the past couple years and we are talking about upgrading all of our computers to Office 2007 which means Access will be updated.  Is this going to cause a problem for me?

Answer (score 5):

Allen Browne, Microsoft access MVP, has written a comprehensive article on Microsoft Access 2007 and upgrading:

[Converting to Access 2007](http://allenbrowne.com/Access2007.html)

Here is an article by Microsoft:

[Transitioning Your Existing Access Applications to Access 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203849.aspx)

In case you are not aware, it is possible to [try 2007 for free](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/FX102855291033.aspx). I would not recommend trying on a PC that you use regularly for other Access work, it is not impossible, but things get awkward.

If you wish to run your 2003 version on 2007, make sure that you create an mde, otherwise you will run into problems. Access 2007 treats several controls in a different way, for example, textboxes with date fields get calendars attached. You will also need to check your references. I also recommend that you [self-certify](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP010397921033.aspx) your projects. Other than that, I have seen posts on a number of problems, but these are usually specific to the poster.

Answer (score 0):

We just recently went through this.

One issue we found was converting *reports* to Excel.  They took that functionality out of Access, so if you do that you'll need to convert it programmatically using the Excel COM object model.  I ended up writing a function to replace the old functionality but you still have a bit of juggling to do.